# Pre-Installed Tails OS Flashdrives

Tags: privacy

I ran across a pretty cool looking dongle that has Tails OS pre-installed, with tutorials on how to use the software.

I wanted to ask the community how safe you guys think this kind of technology is? The founders posted a Binary file at the bottom to be "Transparent", but I wanted some input from the tech community.

Here is the Link - https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/blackcard/black-card-online-privacy-simplified

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. How safe *what* is? Tails? This USB stick?

Comment: Please do not use shortened URLs in posts.

Answer (score 3):

Tails is probably the most secure you can go in terms of choosing an OS but it's still vulnerable and it needs to be used in the proper way I would recommend reading the documentation or instructions on its website. All that Kickstarter is is a pre-installed USB drive with Tails on it which seems stupid since most people already have a USB drive lying around and Tails is open source and free. I would never buy a USB with a pre-installed OS if I was worried about security. Rather make it myself it takes about 5 min.

Comment: The key question is - what else BESIDES Tails could be on the USB.  As chubby_monky points out, it is really easy to install Tails yourself.